# Change HTML structure according to JSON response from a REST API with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have a REST API that returns a JSON object like this

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "status": "open"
}
```

where status can be "open" or "closed". I call this API in an HTML page with a JQuery function:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/question/1", function(data){
           
    
          });
        });
</script>
```

If status from returned JSON object is "open", I want to change my HTML page as following

```
<html>
    <body>
<p>THE QUESTION IS OPEN</p>
    </body>
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/question/1", function(data){
               
        
              });
            });
    </script>
```

Otherwise, if status from returned JSON object is "closed", I want to change my HTML page as following

```
<html>
    <body>
<p>THE QUESTION IS CLOSED</p>
    </body>
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/question/1", function(data){
               
        
              });
            });
    </script>
```

What is the best way to achieve this with JQuery?

Comment: function(data){ if(data.status == "open") ? var statusText = "Question is Open" : var statusText = "Question is Closed"; document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = statusText; }

Comment: If an answer helps you then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('body').prepend()` to put the data right after the open `<body>` tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/question/1", function(data) {
    if (data.status) {
      let str = `The Question is ${data.status}`.toUpperCase()
      $('body').prepend(`<p>${str}</p>`)
    }
  });
});

// for the example

let data = {
  "id": 1,
  "status": "open"
}
if (data.status) {
  let str = `The Question is ${data.status}`.toUpperCase()
  $('body').prepend(`<p>${str}</p>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both `id` and `status` in your JSON object.
If you are going to have status paragraphs for several questions on the same page, this is the way you could do it:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/question/1", function(data) {
      let statusParagraph = document.getElementById("status-" + data.id);
      let statusText;
      if (data.status === "open") {
        statusText = "THE QUESTION IS OPEN";
      } else if (data.status === "closed") {
        statusText = "THE QUESTION IS CLOSED";
      }

      statusParagraph.innerHTML = statusText;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="status-1"></p>
    <p id="status-2"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```